# Can this little code be optimised?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, optimization

It's very simple.

```
List<string> stringArr = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in db.IconTags)
{
    stringArr.Add(item.Tag);
}
string outPut = string.Join(",", stringArr);
```

I wish it was possible to say for instance:

```
string outPut = string.Join(",", db.IconTags.Select(t => t.Tag).ToTArray());
```

Or maybee

```
string outPut = string.Join(",", db.IconTags, t => t.Tag);
```

Isn't there something cool you can do ? I could make my own method, but i was hoping there was something build in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET 4 or newer you can write this:

```
string output = string.Join(",", db.IconTags.Select(t => t.Tag));
```

In .NET 3.5 you need to add a call to `ToArray`:

```
string output = string.Join(",", db.IconTags.Select(t => t.Tag).ToArray());
```

Comment: I tried that! Don't know why i thought i wasn't possible thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

If you are targeting a framework version where you first code works, your first wish also works. It even works without the `.ToArray()`, as the `String.Join` method takes an `IEnumerable<string>`.

In framework 3.5 you would need the `.ToArray()`, but in framework 3.5 your first code doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the number of object instantiations / lambda functions down you can also do

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(var item in db.IconTags) {
    builder.Append(item.Tag).Append(",");
}
// We have one extraneous , so remove it
if(builder.Length > 1) {
    builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);
}
String output = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your alternatives I'm presuming by optimised you mean less lines of code, rather than more efficient computationaly.

Your second alternative should work using Linq:

```
string.Join(",", db.IconTags.Select(iconTag => iconTag.Tag).ToArray());
```

**Update:** As others have said the ToArray can be dropped in .NET 4 and higher.